# Multiple websocket server?

Tags: javascript, java, netbeans, websocket, glassfish

I make a webapp in **javascript** and **java**. Run `localhost:8080` in NetBeans with GlassFish Server 5. I need make in a HTML page a chatroom and a poker tables with 6 clients. Chatroom is fine, used java `websocket ServerEndpoint` and JS client. But I want another channel for the game of poker. I tried to make another `websocket ServerEndpoint` but it doesn't work if i create it on port 8080. How can i solve it? It is important that I can only use java and javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can create a request type in your server code ,and when client connect to that server for different purposes sends relevant type of requests. E.g. chatroom client sends request with a parameter like `{requestType:"chat"}` and other one sends `{requestType:"game"}` among other parameters neccessary for your application.